# Sending Email, without Outlook, using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mail notification triggered to Team-lead when there is change in Target date and Actual date. Target date and Actual date are updated by team members. I do this task by triggering mail using a worksheet change event.

The problem raised when few of the team members don't have the Outlook application configured in their systems or when they used our Office Outlook account from web browsers. This stopped the mail triggering process.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

```vb
Sub CustomMailMessage()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Recipient
Dim Recipients As Recipients

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws01 = wb.Worksheets("DB_1")

datedifferance = ws01.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
Stop
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'  Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("xxxx")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 1

  objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1) 'sender account
  objOutlookMsg.Subject = "Weekly Status-Notification"
  objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "<font face=Calibri> <p style=font-size:11pt>" & _
  "Dear Sir,<br/>" & _
  "<br />" & _
  RangetoHTML(Range(ws01.Cells(1, 9), ws01.Cells(datedifferance, 10))) & _
  "<font face=Calibri> <p style=font-size:11pt>" & _
  "This is system generated mail. Don not reply.<br/>"

  For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients
    objOutlookRecip.Resolve
  Next

  objOutlookMsg.Display
  objOutlookMsg.Send

  Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Theoretically, yes, using ADO... Practically, using Yahoo or Gmail, it is very complicated to make them accept the setting regarding `less secured` way.

Comment: As it is a official we cannot use Yahoo or Gmail. Is there any other way?

Comment: (Also) theoretically, you can use any kind of mail account if you know its configurations and it allows such a sending type (I mean smtp, used port, SSL, account, password etc.)... If you can configure it on your phone, it can be also used for ADO sending way.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sendmail and https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/div/mail4.htm